# ImageMagick error with montage command

Tags: image, montage

I'm stitching 8 images of 8k by 8k pixels in a row using the montage command.

This is what I enter in:

montage -mode concatenate -limit area 0 -tile x1 image1.png image2.png image3.png image4.png image5.png image6.png image7.png image8.png out1.png

This is the error I get out:

montage: magick/quantum.c:215: DestroyQuantumInfo: Assertion `quantum_info->signature == 0xabacadabUL' failed.
Abort

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try 4 images? Or 7? Or 8 images of 4k by 8k?

Answer (score 0):

You may get on better with this command which does what I think you are trying to do:

```
convert +append image{1..8}.png out.png
```

As you can see from the following `identify` command, the images have been laid out side-by-side to make an image 64k pixels wide as a result of the `+append` command. Just FYI, use `-append` to lay them out one above the other in a 64k pixel tall stack.

```
identify out.png 
out.png PNG 64000x8000 64000x8000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2c 62.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Your originally posted command also works fine on my ImageMagick Version:

```
ImageMagick 6.8.9-5 Q16 x86_64 2014-07-29
```